# Can I change a credit card while using reference transactions?

Tags: paypal, reference, transactions

I want to use reference transactions and give the option to users to change their credit card.  It looks like there are required fields like amount that don't apply and can't be zero.

Hopefully I can set it up so:
-User enters credit card info
-I can charge that card different amounts at different intervals
-Invisible PayPal (no express checkout or PayPal billing agreement
-User can change credit cards on my site.

Any ideas, or links to some documentation that can help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be able to update their card details then you'll need to run an Authorization against their new card and store the transaction ID you get back from that as the new ID to use within reference transaction requests.

You could just authorize $1.00 and then immediately void it, for example, to update your system with their new card.